# REGEX: Pattern to detect <embed> tags that are not inside <object> tags?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get the total number of videos that are on a dynamically generated page. To do this I parse the page's html and search for all `<object>`, `<iframe>` and `<embed>` tags. The page won't have any other type of iframe content other than video embed codes so I can be sure that any iframe tag is a video. The problem is some embed codes like Hulu for example have the `<embed>` tag inside the `<object>` tag. So with my current REGEX:

```
'/(<iframe|<object|<embed)/i'
```

this Hulu embed code is seen as 2 videos instead of one:

```
<object id="videoplayer1" width="728" height="407">
   <param name="movie" value='http://www.hulu.com/embed/7qXAa2z1zXKPMw4mBakrRw'></param>
   <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
   <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="never"></param>
   <embed src='http://www.hulu.com/embed/7qXAa2z1zXKPMw4mBakrRw' type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" width="728" height="407" allowscriptaccess='never'></embed>
</object>
```

Rather than searching for all embed tags I only want to search for the ones that aren't encapsulated by `<object>` tags. So the hulu one above will be avoided but one like this will be counted:

```
<embed src="http://www.ebaumsworld.com/player.swf" allowScriptAccess="always" flashvars="id1=81748652" wmode="opaque" width="567" height="345" allowfullscreen="true" />
```

What would the REGEX pattern look like for this, I'm using PHP.

Comment: Don't use regexes, use an XML parser. [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)

Comment: I would still like to know how this can be done using REGEX, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: you're missing the point, it can't and shouldn't be done. Have you read the links I've posted?

Comment: @Colin Hebert I see, but one thing I didn't mention. I am parsing textile markup language before it is converted to html. There is html on the page but that's just the video embed codes. Everything else is textile. Does that make a difference?

Comment: You should be fine because the textile format will be recognised as "Strings" around your XML.

Answer (score 0):

Xml parser with xpath would be my go too